VSCode GO language server and build tags
I have a logging module that works different for prod and dev. I use build tags for this. Everything compiles and works fine, but VSCode doesn't understand what I'm doing and gives errors.
Here is the minimum working code:
For prod (logging/logger_prod.go):
//go:build !dev
// +build !dev

package logging

type Logger struct {
}

func NewLogger() Logger {
    return &Logger{}
}

func (l *Logger) Printf(pattern string, args ...interface{}) {
}

And for dev (logging/logger_dev.go):
//go:build dev
// +build dev

package logging

import "fmt"

type Logger struct {
}

func NewLogger() Logger {
    return &Logger{}
}

func (l *Logger) Printf(pattern string, args ...interface{}) {
    fmt.Printf(pattern, args...)
}

Main file (main.go):
package main

import (
    "github.com/eightlay/azula/internal/modules/logging"
)

func main() {
    logger := logging.NewLogger()
    logger.Printf("Hello, World!")
}

My launch.json:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Dev",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "cmd/gateway/main.go",
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
            "env": {
                "GOFLAGS": "-tags=dev"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch Prod",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "cmd/gateway/main.go",
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
            "env": {
                "GOFLAGS": "-tags=prod"
            }
        }
    ]
}

The error is: "No packages found for open file ***/logger_prod.go.
This file may be excluded due to its build tags; try adding "-tags=" to your gopls "buildFlags" configuration" in logger_prod.go
I've tried to specify buildTags in settings.json - makes no difference.
I've tried to use //go:build prod and // +build prod in the prod file. The errors are: "NewLogger redeclared in this block" for both prod and dev files, "undefined: logging.NewLogger" for main.go.
How should I configure VSCode to solve this issue?

Firstly: Logger is not defined in your code. Second: This is bad design, it's a runtime configuration (why shouldn't production ready code be able to log?) and we have a lot of perfectly configurable loggers, try slog or log. Third: Work for me with VS Code, the tag prod makes no sense, since it's unused. But generally, don't use build tags for runtime configuration.

@eik, thanks, I've corrected the example code to make it better in terms of design. My project is heavily dependent on speed, and I only need the logs for debugging during development, so I want to eliminate all unnecessary code from the prod version.

@eik mage requires the use of tags ("mage") and we do get a warning with VC from gopls. How to we remove this warning ? The advice to don't use tags is not a helpful comment in some case.
